# How promises work in Typescript - I have error in mysql

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, express

I'm working in an Angular 8.3 app with Node 10.17 and Mysql.

When I try to send information in JSON to the Backend I got an error in promises and I don't know what to do.

I've already investigated and I can't find the error

My code

In Angular Component.TS

```
async entrar(): Promise<void>
  { 
      const datosJSON = JSON.stringify(
        {
            NombreP: "Fulanito",
            ApellidoPa: "Perengano",
            ApellidoMa: "merengano",
            Calle: "ejemplo",
            Numero: "9235",
            Colonia: "ejemplo",
            Municipio: "ejemplo",
            CP: new Number(1234),
            NumSeg: "595625634",
            FechaNacimiento: "1234-56-78"
        }
      );

      console.log(datosJSON)
       await this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/alumnos/persona', datosJSON ).subscribe((data) =>{
          this.datos= data;
          console.log(this.datos);
        }) 


  }
```

Comment: First thing first: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: (node:6670) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 12)

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
    at PromisePool.query

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOVerflow! 
The more details you give, the more accurate the answers you get.

I'm seeing a lot of misconceptions here:

1. You should not `JSON.stringify` your object, because then you'll be converting your object into a `string`. Usually in the `POST` request you just send the object as it is or in some other scenarios you can create a `FormData`
2. Observables are not Promises
3. You are not returning anything and certainly not a Promise.
4. Don't subscribe on your Service, if you really really need a promise here, consider:
   `return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/alumnos/persona', datosJSON).toPromise()`
5. Probably you don't need async/await here

Comment: I try this and i didn't work :C.

Comment: I work on express and i have interfaces maybe didn't work that

Comment: Maybe help me more with snapshots.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rjdpPAw.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/bGNWgVN.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wHCQeOs.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/vT3KmD1.png

Comment: You can never send a Javascript object "as is" over http.  Not possible.  It has to be converted to some sort of text-type format, either JSON or FormData or some custom text format.  So, sending a JSON version of an object is a perfectly appropriate thing to do if that's what the recipient is expecting and data types are set appropriately in the post.

Comment: @jfriend00, actually in this scenario (Angular HttpClient) you can and you must do it this way. I'll agree that in case of the fetchAPI you should stringlify your parameters though.

Answer (score 0):

`this.datos = await this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/alumnos/persona', datosJSON ).toPromise();`

In your case the `data` variable inside the subscribe method is returned when the observable is converted to `Promise` and awaited